# i have a problem while using FreeRTOS with keil

Tags: embedded, freertos, cortex-m, keil

i am using keil version 5 and i install all the packages that needed to run freeRTOS on it. but it always gives me an error with portmacro.h

here is some error lines:

```
C:/Users/Mohamed Radwan/AppData/Local/Arm/Packs/ARM/CMSIS-FreeRTOS/10.0.1/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F\portmacro.h(130): error: unknown type name 'inline'

C:/Users/Mohamed Radwan/AppData/Local/Arm/Packs/ARM/CMSIS-FreeRTOS/10.0.1/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F\portmacro.h(130): error: expected ';' after top level declarator
```

its repeated many times as there are many files using it.

any recommend what should i do ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Then come back and [edit] your question and provide the relevant part of the file. A [mre] would also be very helpful.

Comment: If you're compiling with Keil and Arm compiler v5 then you should probably be using the Keil (or RVDS) port of FreeRTOS rather than the GCC port.  Or if you're using Arm compiler v6 (ArmClang) then the GCC port might be OK (I'm not sure).

Comment: What compiler version are you using?  Check under Options For Target->Target tab->Code Generation groupbox.

Comment: What for example is at line 130 of portmacro.h? That is the line the error is reported on.  Knowing what it is complaining about would be useful.  You probably need C99 or C11 support in the C/C++ Settings dialog, which may not be the default.

Comment: @kkrambo thanks for your reply. I found the error that the language C is adjusted to C90 and i fixed it to C99 and it works. the final result tells me there is no error and a lot of warning, but that is fine for me. also if I looked inside the code, I found lines that marked with error but there is no error. do you have any recommendation about that ?

Comment: @Clifford here is the line that gives the error : 
#define portFORCE_INLINE inline __attribute__(( always_inline)).
but when i switch the C language to C99,it works fine and there is no error.

Comment: You need to add that information to the question not hide it in a comment.  SO is a Q&A not a discussion forum.  The question has to stand alone, and the response to issues with the question should be to update the question.  That said, a macro definition can contain anything, it would only become an error in the context of its usage.  So I cannot see how that line could be the one emitting the error message.

Comment: Warnings are not ok, they are usually semantic issues, you should not be ok with that.  You cannot ask about how to resolve subsequent errors without showing both the code and error messages, and you should not ask that in the comments to a different question.  Start a new question.

Comment: _"I found lines that marked with error but there is no error."_ I presume you are talking about the IDE's static analysis rather than actual compiler errors? Hover over the markets and it will tell you the issue.  It is likely to be more picky than the compiler, but it is also probably right.